# Replace list of symbols in an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have an expression:

```
exp = a+b+c
```

and a list containing all the symbols of my expression:

```
syms = {a,b,c}
```

and I would like to replace the symbols with numerical values. I have a list containing the numerical values:

```
val = {1,2,3}
```

and I would like to perform something like this:

```
 exp/.syms->val
```

to get: `1+2+3`

But this doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: Have a look at `Thread`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
  exp /. Thread[syms ->  val]
  (* 6 *)
```

the reason `exp /. syms ->  val` does not work can be seen by doing trace:

```
  Trace[exp /. syms ->  val]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see it was looking for `a+b+c/.{a,b,c}->{1,2,3}` and since there is no pattern `{a,b,c}` then it does not work.

With `Thread`, you basically break it to `a->1,b->2,c->3` then it works.

Answer (score 1):

> to get: 1+2+3

you can use any of:

```
exp /. Thread[syms -> (Defer /@ val)]
exp /. Thread[syms -> (HoldForm /@ val)]
Defer[Evaluate@exp] /. Thread[syms -> val]
HoldForm[Evaluate@exp] /. Thread[syms -> val]
```